# Unable to select currency value in ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I have code in HTML

```
{{cm.currency}}
<select name="currency" id="currency" ng-model="cm.currency" class="form-control"
       ng-options="c.code as c.code +' ' +c.name for c in currencies track by c.code">
</select>
```

in controller

```
 $scope.cm={currency:'INR'};
 $scope.currencies=[
     {code: "USD", id: 1, name: "US Dollar" ,symbol: "$"},
     {code: "INR", id: 2, name: "Indian Rupee", symbol: "₹"},
     {code: "EUR", id: 3, name: "Euro", symbol: "€"},
 ];
```

`{{cm.currency}}` is shoing correct currency value but it is not selecting value in ng-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-selected` directive to bind default selected option.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select nname="currency" id="currency" ng-model="cm.currency" class="form-control"
   ng-selected=" cm.currency == option.code"  
   ng-options="option.code as option.code+' '+option.name for option in currencies">          
</select>
<br/> <tt>Selected value: {{cm.currency}}</tt>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cm={currency:'INR'};
    $scope.currencies=[{code: "USD", id: 1, name: "US Dollar" ,symbol: "$"},{code: "INR", id: 2, name: "Indian Rupee", symbol: "₹"},{code: "EUR", id: 3, name: "Euro", symbol: "€"}];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `track by` clause:

```
<select nname="currency" id="currency" ng-model="cm.currency" class="form-control"
  ̶n̶g̶-̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶=̶"̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶c̶o̶d̶e̶+̶'̶ ̶'̶+̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶i̶e̶s̶ 
               ̶t̶r̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶i̶d̶"̶

  ng-options="option.code as option.code+' '+option.name for option in currencies">
```

From the Docs:

> ### `select as` and `track by`
>
> > Be careful when using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression.
>
> — [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - `select as` and `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-)

### THE DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cm={currency:'INR'};
    $scope.currencies=[
       {code: "USD", id: 1, name: "US Dollar" ,symbol: "$"},
       {code: "INR", id: 2, name: "Indian Rupee", symbol: "₹"},
       {code: "EUR", id: 3, name: "Euro", symbol: "€"}
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select nname="currency" id="currency" ng-model="cm.currency"
            class="form-control"
            ng-options="option.code as option.code+' '+option.name for
                        option in currencies">          
    </select>
    <br/>
    <tt>Selected value: {{cm.currency}}</tt>

</select>

</body>
```